# Format output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numpy

I have the following function which transforms list of numbers:

```
import numpy as np
from math import *


def walsh_transform(x):
    if len(x) > 3:
        n = len(x)
        m = trunc(log(n, 2))
        x = x[0:2 ** m]
        h2 = [[1, 1], [1, -1]]
        for i in range(m - 1):
            if i == 0:
                h = np.kron(h2, h2)
            else:
                h = np.kron(h, h2)

        return np.dot(h, x) / 2. ** m

arr = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

print(walsh_transform(arr))
```

It returns output `[ 0.625 -0.125 -0.125  0.125  0.625 -0.125 -0.125  0.125]`

How can I make it return output `[0.625, -0.125, -0.125,  0.125,  0.625, -0.125, -0.125,  0.125]` ? I.e. comma-separated values?

Comment: My personal opinion is that you should explicitly say that you want the output in the form of a list, rather than making readers scrutinize your actual and desired outputs to see what the difference is. I could just be unobservant, but it took me a few readings to see it.

Comment: Hope we were able to assist you. If so, please mark the answer used as correct :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Just cast the end result to a list, since lists print out in the format you want.

```
print(list(walsh_transform(arr)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `return [z for z in np.dot(h, x) / 2. ** m]` instead of `return np.dot(h, x) / 2. ** m`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the resultant array to list to get a output as you wanted.

```
w = walsh_transform(arr) # w = [ 0.625 -0.125 -0.125  0.125  0.625 -0.125 -0.125  0.125]

print(list(w)) # output = [0.625, -0.125, -0.125, 0.125, 0.625, -0.125, -0.125, 0.125]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `repr`

```
print(repr(walsh_transform(arr))) # output = [0.625, -0.125, -0.125, 0.125, 0.625, -0.125, -0.125, 0.125]
```

Alternatively, you can cast it to a list:

```
print(list(walsh_transform(arr))) # output = [0.625, -0.125, -0.125, 0.125, 0.625, -0.125, -0.125, 0.125]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is replace the whitespace with commas.

re.sub function should work too.

Comment: No, ``walsh_transform()`` does not return a string. Please check ;)

Comment: `walsh_transform()` is returning an numpy array, not a string.